# Small generalisations of Wallis products

Tags: analytic-number-theory, infinite-products

In 1656, John Wallis found a famous product expansion for $\pi$ :
$\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{2}{1}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3}\frac{4}{5}\frac{6}{5}\frac{6}{7}\frac{8}{7}\frac{8}{9}...$

I recently learned there was a similar formula for our friend $e$ where each term of denominator between $2^{k-1}$ and $2^k$ are to the power of $2^{-k}$ : $\frac{e}{2} = (\frac{2}{1})^{1/2}(\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3})^{1/4}(\frac{4}{5}\frac{6}{5}\frac{6}{7}\frac{8}{7})^{1/8}...$

So I had fun coding them with Python and I tried changing some parameters :

Suppose $q$ a real number, we can define $f(q) = (\frac{2}{1})^{1/q}(\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3})^{1/q^2}(\frac{4}{5}\frac{6}{5}\frac{6}{7}\frac{8}{7})^{1/q^3}...$

- With $f(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $f(2) = \frac{e}{2}$, are there other famous $f(q)$ ?

Also can we define $f_n(q)$ for which the terms to the powers are not essentially grouped by powers of $2$ but by powers of $n$ so that $f_2(q) = f(q)$.

- $f_3(3)$ might surprisingly be $\sqrt5$

And finally I thought maybe powers of $1/q$ were too restrictive and that we could work on all natural numbers so I tried this :

- It looks like this product equals Sierpinski's Constant : $K \stackrel{?}{=}\frac{2}{1}(\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3})^{1/2}(\frac{4}{5}\frac{6}{5})^{1/3}(\frac{6}{7}\frac{8}{7})^{1/4}$...

As you may have noticed I only made my engine compute results but I can't prove them true nor false, that's why I come to you in case someone has any idea of why are these results. And if you could prove me wrong I'd be so glad you point out my errors. Remember I'm just opening questions I hope you'll enjoy having a try.

Thank you !

Comment: The last product
$\frac{2}{1}(\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3})^2(\frac{4}{5}\frac{6}{5})^3(\frac{6}{7}\frac{8}{7})^4 \cdots$ 
should "diverge to zero", because the $n$-th factor
$\bigl(\!\frac{(2n-2)2n}{(2n-1)^2}\!\bigr)^n$
has logarithm $-1/(4n) + O(1/n^2)$, and $\sum_n -1/(4n) = -\infty$.

Comment: Very interesting. To how many decimal places did you compute f_3(3) ?  It looks to me as if the first thing worth exploring might be f_q(q).

Comment: $\log f(1/x)$ is a power series with radius $1$ but I don’t see any handle

Comment: When  you group by 3 do you mean $(\frac{2}{1})(\frac{2}{3} \frac{4}{3} \frac{4}{5})...$ or $(\frac{2}{1})(\frac{2}{5} \frac{4}{5} \frac{6}{5})...$ ?
Trying to figure out your $f_3(3)$

Comment: Could you add a reference for $f(2)$? Btw is it $e$ or $e/2$?

Comment: I computed $f_3(3)$ (which I mean $\frac{2}{1}(\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3}\frac{4}{5})$... up to 10000 steps and first 3 digits are right but I know these are slow converging products. Also $f(2)$ is indeed $\frac{e}{2}$, I corrected my error, you can find it anywhere by searching for Willis product form of $e$.

Comment: One can find some related products in the follow paper by Sondow and Yi: [New Wallis- and Catalan-Type Infinite Products for $\pi, e,$ and $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.4169/000298910x523399.pdf?casa_token=7w7niI0rY8wAAAAA:lv6DjMmdl7Gox6kmXnxkqFHWyusS54BvGVqdO29cls_nttO3tsWCvjo-G6MlYB9kkAOVAvnJqfQtkeuhxM-_fqARLBZF-_TdF8sFhf00XuEVTwrV3B20Sg)

Comment: (same paper on arxiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.2712.pdf)

Comment: I missed-wrote that part : in the Sierpinski's Constant part powers are wrong, I'm correcting it now